# using unescape, possible fallback?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, escaping, angular5

I'm currently rewriting an angular1 app to angular5.

The authentication service calls this line:

```
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(password)))
```

Unescape seems to be depreciated but without it some passwords don't work (don't ask me why, I think it has something to do with some special characters, the testpassword contained a §)

What would be the best way to handle this? Can I throw this function out somehow? My Editor doesn't even know it and shows this line as faulty (Intellij).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems odd.

Anyways `unescape` has been replaced with `decodeURI`.. For verbosity you can try:

```
btoa(decodeURI(encodeURIComponent(password)))
```

Comment: no, i tryed this. The resulting string is diffrent and I get a 401 (unauthorized) error